# How to send the clipboard my own content after clicking ctrl+C using C#?

Tags: c#, keyboard, clipboard, ctrl

How can I replace the copied text on the clipboard with my own?

When I'm clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, my clipboard still consists of marked text, but not with "Hello there".

```
if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.C) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
{
     Clipboard.SetDataObject("Hello there");
}
```

P.S., `MessageBox` works normally.

Comment: What?Did I use C in tag? Sry that was my mistake.

Comment: What about Clipboard.SetText() method?

Comment: It gives 0x800401D0 exception error

Comment: But SetDataObject works when i set it to other keys. Problem is when i want to use CTRL + C.

Answer (score 0):

Try key event handler like this.

```
private void KeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.C && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        Clipboard.SetDataObject("Hello there");
    }
}
```